# Migrating to proj API 6+ without forcing crs input

Tags: gis, proj

I'm posting this question here instead of gis.stackexchange.com because I think this is more of a programming question than a GIS question.

The [proj migration guide](https://proj.org/development/migration.html#version-4-to-6-api-migration) explains how to convert code to proj 6 and later by turning code that looked like this (error handling omitted for brevity):

```c
projPJ pj_longlat = pj_init_plus(source);
projPJ pj_merc = pj_init_plus(target);
pj_transform(pj_longlat, pj_merc, ...)
```

into code that looks like this:

```c
PJ *P = proj_create_crs_to_crs(PJ_DEFAULT_CTX, source, target, NULL);
proj_trans(P, PJ_FWD, ...);
```

This is what was done in several projects including [mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/commit/88241b32eeaccdc9eda7b92b7e7b6d4deac88e12) but there is one downside: with the new code, both `source` and `target` must be a CRS or otherwise `proj_create_crs_to_crs` will fail with:

```
proj_create_operations: source_crs is not a CRS
```

This means that some applications (for example I successfully used mapnik rendering with a `+proj=pipeline` projection, which is not a CRS) are not possible anymore.

In [a proj issue report](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/3161) a developer points out that it should be possible to avoid `proj_create_crs_to_crs` by using `proj_create` manually. But if I understand it correctly, then to create a `PJ` object that transforms from `source` to `target` (and vice-versa) I need a pipeline but if one of my projections contains a pipeline, then this will not work because I cannot have nested pipelines.

So how would I convert code from the PROJ 4 to PROJ 6 API but without removing the ability to input arbitrary transformations, even those that are not a CRS?

### Edit

I asked the same question on the PROJ mailing list and got [this very helpful reply from Even Rouault](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/proj/2022-April/010597.html). I'll use that to try and implement a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With [help from Even Rouault](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/proj/2022-April/010597.html) I managed to submit a pull request to mapnik which will use an alternative code path if the input transforms are not a CRS:

https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/pull/4309

Essentially, this is doing the following (error checking omitted for brevity):

```cpp
ctx_ = proj_context_create();
std::string crs_source = pj_add_type_crs_if_needed(source);
PJ *src = proj_create(ctx_, crs_source.c_str());
std::string crs_dest = pj_add_type_crs_if_needed(dest);
PJ *dst = proj_create(ctx_, crs_dest.c_str());
if (proj_is_crs(src) && proj_is_crs(dst)) {
    /* insert proj_create_crs_to_crs and friends from
     * the official migration guide here */
} else {
    /* either src or dst is not a crs, so we need to set
     * up the pipeline ourselves */
    auto formatter = osgeo::proj::io::PROJStringFormatter::create();
    formatter->startInversion();
    formatter->ingestPROJString(source);
    formatter->stopInversion();
    formatter->ingestPROJString(dest);
    transform_ = proj_create(ctx_, formatter->toString().c_str());
}
proj_destroy(src);
proj_destroy(dst);
return transform_;
```

Most notably, the above alternative codepath does not call `proj_normalize_for_visualization`, so the user is on their own in case they provide a non-CRS transform that would need normalization.

The function `pj_add_type_crs_if_needed` comes from the PROJ codebase in src/4D_api.cpp and adds a  `+type=crs` suffix to a PROJ string (if it is a PROJ string) and can be written like this:

```cpp
std::string pj_add_type_crs_if_needed(const std::string &str) {
    std::string ret(str);
    if ((str.rfind("proj=", 0) == 0 || str.rfind("+proj=", 0) == 0 ||
         str.rfind("+init=", 0) == 0 || str.rfind("+title=", 0) == 0) &&
        str.find("type=crs") == std::string::npos) {
        ret += " +type=crs";
    }
    return ret;
}
```